# How do I append new line break and retain the previous line break after an event is fired?

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

Im making a chat app and need to append messages. The issue is that the new messages are all inline, I need a way to create a new line after a message is sent and not delete the previous message.

I have used '\n' but it only provides spaces. I tried using innerHTML but it replaces everything so the previous messages are lost.

I want to use vanilla js to solve this problem.

Essentially I want to convert this line of Jquery into js:

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
  $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your new lines in a block-level element (I've used `section` in this example). To avoid clearing the whole log whenever you add a line you could use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) which allows you to direct where your HTML ends up.

```js
const area = document.querySelector('textarea');
const save = document.querySelector('button');
const log = document.querySelector('#log');

save.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {
  const { value } = area;
  const html = `<section>${value}</section>`;
  log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  area.value = '';
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<button>Save</button>
<h4>Log</h4>
<main id="log" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping the message in a new tag, such as `<p>` or `<li>`? You could also give these tags a class which has `display: block;` which in most circumstances will display them on a new line.